# Pass a String in Select query - SOQL

Tags: visualforce, soql, custom-field, query, database

I have a `String` that contains some custom fields of `Account`.
I want to pass a `String` in a `Select` query like this :

```
String myString = 'myCustomField1__c, myCustomField2__c';
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, Name, myString FROM Account];
```

How can I do this ?

I'm able to do it with `Database.query(...)` but I'd prefer the method above if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't combine SOQL and dynamic SOQL(`Database.query(query_string)`) - if you have to use this string with list of field you have to use dynamic SOQL.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm

Comment: Yes, that what i'm thinking. Thanks for the reply.